# Google Chrome NETWORL_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101

Tags: javascript, xml, google-chrome

How can i start my chrome with this command  : 
--allow-file-access-from-files
how to do it where to go????
I guess this is the only solution for that annoying error, i concluded that after sufing through Chrome's official blog...So any help??

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to kill Chrome's process then follow the instructions as listed at http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/run-chromium-with-flags